# Automatically switch between monitor 1 and monitor 2 every x minutes

Tags: windows, external-display

At work we are planning to install 2 display monitors back to back (so at most one display can be seen by any person). There will be 1 computer that will display a different application on each display monitor.

I want to be able to switch displays from 1 to 2 and vice versa, so people do not have to move themselves to the back of the monitor to see the opposite side (monitor). I need a script that will switch display every x seconds.

How can I do it?

Comment: why dont you show both monitors at the same time?

Comment: I'm confused. Can you confirm -there are 2 displays and one computer.

Comment: If only one display can be seen at a time, then does the other display have to be different to the one I can see.

Comment: because the 2 monitors (connected to 1 computer) will be in the middle of a team, the monitor 1 one has to toggle to monitor 2 like every 1 minute. (it is a seilling rack that you can attach 2 monitor one in the back of the other. monitor one will display east. side and monitor 2 west side. the 2 monitors will not show the samething, like one will be for video security and the other one wan alert...